# Ubuntu installation failed every time after choosing "install ubuntu alongside window 7"

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows-7

I want to install Ubuntu with window 7 as a dual boot PC.

After Booting from pendrive when I choose "intall ubuntu on Hard disk" , then installation window comes, I choose "do not connect to wifi right now". Then choose "installation type alongside window 7". After clicking "continue" a black scrren comes for 2 seconds and then my pc again restart and **window 7 starts every time**. (after step 4 as mention on http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest)

I am using my pen drive to boot (I made it Ubuntu bootable from http://www.pendrivelinux.com ) and i tried this installation using wifi connected and disconnected as well as.But i prefer to disconnected during installation.and these are not the actual problem.

(After booting from pen drive selecting after install ubuntu on Hard disk it goes to select language option and then prepare to install Ubuntu and after the step "install alongside window7" pc again boot to window 7 (That is the Problem). 
But first and second time after boot instead of installation window it directs into a black screen command modes where lots of commands are shown and it shows write help command.Then i am unable to do anything and have to turn off my laptop with power key.)

I want to install Ubuntu in D drive alongside Window 7. Is it okay or wrong and how to do this.

**But actual problem is my ubuntu installation fails after selecting "install ubuntu alongside window7"**

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 desktop- i38.iso (735,358,976 bytes)

Md5sum is : d791352694374f1c478779f7f4447a3f

- Laptop model: compaq presario cq62 -112tu
- RAM: 2 GB
- Intel i5 430 M processor
- 290 GB HDD: C drive 29.2 GB free of 49 GB;
- D drive 121 GB free of 122 GB and
- E drive 21.3 GB free of 127 GB
- and HDD is simple (not dynamic)

PLEASE HELP!!!! THANKS IN ADVANCE.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to install Ubuntu alongside your Windows 7. You can try this....

Before you start the installation, create a separate disk partition in Windows. Insert your bootable disc/USB device. Follow the instructions. When you see the disk chooser, select your newly created hard disk partition. Select the `Change` option from below. Format it to `ext4` and select mount point `/`. Press okay. Below, you'll see option for bootloader device. Click on it and choose the `topmost` option (It'll have some information about your HDD i.e. its size, manufacturer etc). Click continue when you are asked for `swap partition` option. If you do want to create a `swap partition` you'll have to create another partition. You won't need it in normal use anyway.

Answer (score -2):

The solution is very simple ... 
Install EaseUs partition in technician mode ... 
Then go to HDD menue then click with right and chose convert to basic HDD ... 
There is a risk to loose your files but I have not loss them ... 
Then you will install ubuntu alongside windows ...